# How to change product image on hover?

Tags: magento2, product-images, products, image-preview

I am trying to change Image on Hover in all product. Any help regarding this.It's not about product placeholder. Problem is that I am not able to get another type of image. **product_page_large_image** and **product_base_image** is same output but when I am trying with **product_small_image**, it's not working.

All thing oK, I have to get another image from the backend. For example, product Have two Image one is default show and one is showing after hover.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
<div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid"  >
    <?php // Product Image    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                        <span style="width:270px;" class="product-image-container">
                            <span style="padding-bottom: 137%;" class="product-image-wrapper" >
                                <?php
                                $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                                    ->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')
                                    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                    ->resize(270, 404)
                                    ->getUrl();

                                $imageUr2 = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
                                    ->init($_product, 'product_base_image')
                                    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                                    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                                    ->resize(270, 404)
                                    ->getUrl();
                                ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $imageUr2; ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>';"/>
                                <!-- <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php //echo $imageUrl; ?>" onmouseover="alert('And yet another one!')" />
                                <!--<div class="bl_black"></div><!-->
                           </span>
                        </span>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I guess for a different image (hover) you need to set a thumbnail image and not a small image? I know it seems stupid but that worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check with below code.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php echo ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
<div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
        <span style="width:270px;" class="product-image-container">
            <span style="padding-bottom: 137%;" class="product-image-wrapper">
            <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
                $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
                $imgCNT = 1;
                foreach ($images as $child) {
                    if ($imgCNT == 1) {
                        $imgurl1 = $child->getUrl();
                    } elseif ($imgCNT == 2) {
                        $imgurl2 = $child->getUrl();
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                    $imgCNT++;
                }
                $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(270, 404)->getUrl(); ?>
                <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>"
                     onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo ($imgurl2) ? $imgurl2 : $imageUrl ?>';"
                     onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>';"/>
                <div class="bl_black"></div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Yoges@ when I used this code not getting any image or product

Comment: Hello yogesh@->init($_product, 'product_page_image_large') is working but when i change this ->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small') it's not working  any idea

Comment: hello yogesh you there?

Comment: Hello sanjay..,

Comment: This code is  working , but  need two or three time to refresh then it's  working@ i think any js  problem, why needs two or three time refresh the website

Comment: please check in console is there any js error, till i know there should be js loading error $.widget is not a function OR can not read property etc.

Comment: when open in browser first time its working good, after that i when i click other page and again come on this page the  page is showing nothing. and console is also blank

Comment: I think In line js is creating problem can  you suggest js with function or js ,

Comment: inline javascript code is working perfect on my case, there should be some other issue. please check with console

Comment: yog can you review this code . getting truble with this code

Answer (score 4):

I made this to work in my site https:/www.gamesunited.com.kw

1. First I added Attribute 'hover_image' with Catalog Input Type for Store Owner as Media Image

2. Then in the attribute setting StoreFront properties "Used in Product Listing" is set as 'Yes'

There is bug and this option does not show in admin attribute setting page. Refer the image to show that.
  [image]

3. In my custom theme etc/view.xml I added

[image]
4. In my custom theme Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml I added following

```
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$hoverimg = 'category_page_grid_hover';
$hoverimg = 'category_page_list_hover';
```

[image]
and then

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" tabindex="-1">
  <?php $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image);
        $productImageUrl = $productImage->getUrl(); ?>
<img class="product-image-photo default_image" src="<?php echo $productImageUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $productImage->getLabel(); ?>"/>

 <?php $productHoverImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $hoverimg);
      $productHoverImageUrl = $productHoverImage->getUrl(); ?>
<?php if($productImageUrl != str_replace("/thumbnail/","/small_image/",$productHoverImageUrl)): ?>
<img class="product-image-photo hover_image" src="<?php echo $productHoverImageUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $productHoverImage->getLabel(); ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>                        
</a>
```

5. and then CSS Styling

```
.products-grid .item .item-inner .box-image:hover .hover_image,
.products-list .item .item-inner .box-image-list:hover .hover_image
{
   opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.hover_image
{
 left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code to product listing file on [YourTheme]=>[Magento_Catalog]=>[templates]=>[product]=>[list.phtml]

Get another image of product using the code below:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
$imgCNT = 1;
foreach($images as $child){
if($imgCNT==1)
{$imgurl1=$child->getUrl();}
elseif($imgCNT==2)
{$imgurl2=$child->getUrl(); }
else
{break;}
$imgCNT++;
}
```

and add that both image url on product image like below added image

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgurl1; ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $imgurl2; ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $imgurl1; ?>';"/>
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Yes @sanjay please

Comment: yes @sanjay please

Comment: both are alternate, you can add anyone code,

Comment: Hi yogesh , I know you can solve it ,please see this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172694/i-want-show-image-randomly-on-mouse-hover-and-mouse-out

Comment: hey@ yogesh you there Need your help

Comment: You should never `load()` a product unless absolutely necessary. Since this it called multiple times when rendering a product collection it makes this code super heavy and inefficient. A better alternative would be to fetch the images from the database directly.
Also using `$objectManager` is never a good idea.